# CLIENT_ERROR: invalid S3 ARN for primary source

Tags: angular, github, amazon-s3, xcodebuild, aws-codepipeline

everyone, I am currently attempting to build a CodePipeline between my git repository and an S3 bucket for my Angular application but can't seem to get a build to pass.  Specifically, I am getting the error in the title.

Essentially, I followed step for step this guide: https://medium.com/faun/ci-cd-with-angular-8-github-and-aws-codepipeline-b83d2b01e594

And for the most part everything went as described in the guide.  However, there is a part where it says to modify the S3_Bucket attribute in the buildspec.  I'll post below an example of what mine looks like (url name changed, but format is the same.)

Based on the error, I feel like that is probably where the issue is but I can't seem to get the url in a format that will make the build be successful.

```xml
version: 0.2

env:
    variables:
        CACHE_CONTROL: "86400"
        S3_BUCKET: "NOTMYACTUALDOMAIN.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
        BUILD_FOLDER: "dist"
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        nodejs: 10
    commands:
        - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
        - npm install
        - npm install -g @angular/cli
  build:
    commands:
```

Here's the Phase Table of the build if that helps at all.

SUBMITTED   Succeeded<1 sec Oct 26, 2019 1:41 AM    Oct 26, 2019 1:41 AM

QUEUED  Succeeded<1 sec Oct 26, 2019 1:41 AM    Oct 26, 2019 1:41 AM

PROVISIONING    Succeeded 12 secs Oct 26, 2019 1:41 AM  Oct 26, 20191:41 AM

DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Failed CLIENT_ERROR: invalid S3 ARN for primary source  3 secs  Oct 26, 2019 1:41 AM    Oct 26, 2019 1:41 AM

FINALIZING  Succeeded 4 secsOct 26, 2019 1:41 AM    Oct 26, 2019 1:41 AM

COMPLETED   Succeeded

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you trying to start the build from CodeBuild directly? Since the build project was created via CodePipeline, its Source is set as CODEPIPELINE [1] which means the Build project cannot be invoked by itself (it will not have a Source in that case) and must be invoked through CodePipeline (e.g. via "Release Change" button on CodePipeline Console). In the latter case, CodePipeline will provide the primary source artifact to the Build project.

[1] "source-type" - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/create-project.html#create-project-cli

Comment: Yes, this ended up being the problem, the build initially failed in Pipeline due to not have proper role authorizations and then after I fixed that I kept trying to run the build from Build rather than Pipeline.  As soon as I ran it again from the Pipeline page everything cleared up.  Thanks for the help!